# How to create a WP Cron hooks based on schedules from Advanced cron manager plugin?

Tags: wp-cron, automatic-updates, scheduled-posts, automation, wp-remote-get

I need to run the following script once per 24 hours:

(1)
http:domain.com/wp-cron.php?import_key=Iq_GCn7v0&import_id=36&action=trigger

the following one to run after the above, once or twice per 24 hours.

(2)
http:domain.com/wp-cron.php?import_key=Iq_GCn7v0&import_id=36&action=processing

I created both cron under ACM dashboard and added the following hooks in my functions php file:

```
if( !wp_next_scheduled( 'myjobs_trigger' ) ) {
  wp_schedule_event( time(), 'daily', 'myjobs_trigger' );
}
add_action( 'myjobs_trigger', 'update_myjob_trigger' );
function update_myjob_trigger() {
  // do whatever you want
  wp_remote_get('http:domain.com/wp-cron.php?import_key=Iq_GCn7v0&import_id=36&action=trigger');
}//end
//Run the execution script Once every 30 minutes
if( !wp_next_scheduled( 'myjobs_process' ) ) {
  wp_schedule_event( time(), '60*30', 'myjobs_trigger' );
}
add_action( 'myjobs_process', 'update_myjob_process' );
function update_myjob_process   () {
  // do whatever you want
wp_remote_get('http:domain.com/wp-cron.php?import_key=Iq_GCn7v0&import_id=36&action=processing');
}//end
```

I'm missing a few things here.
First I can't properly figure out how to write a function that first test the triggering cron (1) has run before running the processing cron (2).
I couldn't also properly write the timing for the processing cron (2) which should be 2 times daily after the triggering cron (1) ran.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: I don't get why are you using a plugin for this

Comment: Client said there is no help from host and I can think of any other solution. do you?

Comment: Why the wordpress core code is not enough? no plugin is likely to replace it

Comment: do you wanna help maybe. That's all my point of been here, because can't think of another way. wp-cron fires up on page visit only and I need to run the cron at specific times, visit or no visit. It's a job placement site that needs to display always the latest offers with time stamp.

Comment: If you need the cron to be on specific time then you have to use the OS cron

Comment: You are not been helpful @MarkKaplun

Comment: Sorry, this site is not a replacement for hiring profesional help. If you must have an "helpful" answer, you should just pay someone

Comment: @exedesign2 Really, you should use OS cron and disable WP cron in `wp-config.php`. There is no way that WP cron runs without a visit – OS cron can bridge that gap. There are enough sources that show you how to (both on and off site).